# Access 3rd and 4th level JSON data using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

great day!
I have a small problem with php accessing the 3rd and 4th level data in a json array. As per the json data below I have the "servicelist" and from this servicelist I have a bunch of information like the IP Address of the server and the processes running under it.

My problem is how to loop through this ip address and the values of the services under it using php.

the json data is below:

```html
{
  "format_version": 0,
  "result": {
    "query_time": 1480964905000,
    "cgi": "statusjson.cgi",
    "user": "nagiosadmin",
    "query": "servicelist",
    "query_status": "released",
    "program_start": 1480936959000,
    "last_data_update": 1480964898000,
    "type_code": 0,
    "type_text": "Success",
    "message": ""
  },
  "data": {
    "selectors": {
      "hostgroup": "Premium"
    },
    "servicelist": {
      "104.11.2.25": {
        "DISK": 2,
        "L2TP": 2,
        "LOAD": 2,
        "OPENVPN TCP": 2,
        "OPENVPN UDP": 2,
        "PING": 2,
        "PPTP": 2,
        "PROCESS": 2,
        "USERS": 2,
        "XL2TPD": 2
      },
      "104.44.13.17": {
        "DISK": 2,
        "L2TP": 2,
        "LOAD": 2,
        "OPENVPN TCP": 2,
        "OPENVPN UDP": 2,
        "PING": 4,
        "PPTP": 2,
        "PROCESS": 2,
        "USERS": 2,
        "XL2TPD": 2
      },
      "14.244.15.16": {
        "DISK": 2,
        "L2TP": 2,
        "LOAD": 2,
        "OPENVPN TCP": 2,
        "OPENVPN UDP": 2,
        "PING": 4,
        "PPTP": 2,
        "PROCESS": 2,
        "USERS": 2,
        "XL2TPD": 2
      }
   }
   }
}
```

my incomplete php code is below:

```
    <?php

$username = "thisuser";
$password = "this password";
$url = "http://nagios.services.com/nagios/cgi-bin/statusjson.cgi?query=servicelist&hostgroup=Servers&hoststatus=up+down+unreachable+pending&servicestatus=ok+warning+critical+unknown+pending";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);

foreach($jsonData->data as $thisData){
    foreach($thisData->servicelist as $values)
    {
        foreach($values as $result){
            echo $result->LOAD;
        }
    }  
}

?>
```

Basically what i want is to put the information in a table like:
[Sample HTML Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojjij.png)

Comment: your `$jsonData` is basically an array and can be accessed as so.

Comment: Its nice if you at least post a valid piece of JSON

Comment: `$result->LOAD` this is wrong. `$result` is an integer, it does not have any properties (such as `LOAD`)

Comment: @RiggsFolly i updated the json to be valid.

Comment: @Steve can you give me a more accurate information please?

Comment: @bassxzero it will be nicer if you can show me how. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out this code:

```
<?php

     $username = "thisuser";
     $password = "this password";
     $url = "http://nagios.services.com/nagios/cgi-bin/statusjson.cgi?query=servicelist&hostgroup=Servers&hoststatus=up+down+unreachable+pending&servicestatus=ok+warning+critical+unknown+pending";

     $ch = curl_init();

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

     $jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
     curl_close($ch);

     foreach($jsonData['data']['servicelist'] as $ip => $service_list) {
        echo "<p>IP Address: {$ip}, Load: {$service_list['LOAD']}</p>";
    }

?>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php

     $username = "thisuser";
     $password = "this password";
     $url = "http://nagios.services.com/nagios/cgi-bin/statusjson.cgi?query=servicelist&hostgroup=Servers&hoststatus=up+down+unreachable+pending&servicestatus=ok+warning+critical+unknown+pending";

     $ch = curl_init();

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

     $jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
     curl_close($ch);

     foreach($jsonData['data']['servicelist'] as $ip => $service_list) {
        echo "<p>IP Address: {$ip}, Load: {$service_list['LOAD']}</p>";
    }

    $ip_status = array(
       '1' => 'Pending',
       '2' => 'OK',
       '4' => 'Warning',
       '8' => 'Unknown',
       '16' => 'Critical'
    );

?>

<html>
  <head>
     <title>IP Data</title>
     <style>
        table {
           border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table th, table tr td {
           text-align: center;
           border: 1px solid #ccc;
           text-transform: uppercase;
           padding: 10px 20px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
         <th>IP Address</th>
         <th>Load</th>
         <th>OpenVPN TCP</th>
         <th>OpenVPN UDP</th>
         <th>Users</th>
         <th>L2TP</th>
         <th>PPTP</th>
         <th>XL2TPD</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <?php if(!empty($jsonData['data']['servicelist'])): ?>
              <?php foreach($jsonData['data']['servicelist'] as $ip => $service_list): ?>
                  <tr>
                     <td><?= $ip ?></td>
                     <td><?= $ip_status[$service_list['LOAD']] ?></td>
                     <td><?= $ip_status[$service_list['OPENVPN TCP']] ?></td>
                     <td><?= $ip_status[$service_list['OPENVPN UDP']] ?></td>
                     <td><?= $ip_status[$service_list['USERS']] ?></td>
                     <td><?= $ip_status[$service_list['L2TP']] ?></td>
                     <td><?= $ip_status[$service_list['PPTP']] ?></td>
                     <td><?= $ip_status[$service_list['XL2TPD']] ?></td>
                  </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here is the whole code you're looking for. Hope it helps!

Comment: not working just showing a blank screen. anyways thanks for the help. on second note: its a http error 500

Comment: I actually had a variable called `$services_list` in my code which is what caused your page to appear blank. I've now replaced the variable to `$jsonData`. You can check it out now.

Comment: Is working.. but i would like it to be on a table as per this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojjij.png)

Comment: How the value `OK` in each column is evaluated?

Comment: '1' => 'pending', '2' => 'OK', '4' => 'warning', '8' => 'unknown', '16' => 'critical'

Comment: Wow! works great!
I;ve accepted your answer. thanks a bunch for the great help. :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how you can process your data structure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);


$s = '{
    "format_version": 0,
    "result": {
        "query_time": 1480964905000,
        "cgi": "statusjson.cgi",
        "user": "nagiosadmin",
        "query": "servicelist",
        "query_status": "released",
        "program_start": 1480936959000,
        "last_data_update": 1480964898000,
        "type_code": 0,
        "type_text": "Success",
        "message": ""
    },
    "data": {
        "selectors": {
            "hostgroup": "Premium"
        },
        "servicelist": {
            "104.11.2.25": {
                "DISK": 2,
                "L2TP": 2,
                "LOAD": 2,
                "OPENVPN TCP": 2,
                "OPENVPN UDP": 2,
                "PING": 2,
                "PPTP": 2,
                "PROCESS": 2,
                "USERS": 2,
                "XL2TPD": 2
            },
            "104.44.13.17": {
                "DISK": 2,
                "L2TP": 2,
                "LOAD": 2,
                "OPENVPN TCP": 2,
                "OPENVPN UDP": 2,
                "PING": 4,
                "PPTP": 2,
                "PROCESS": 2,
                "USERS": 2,
                "XL2TPD": 2
            },
            "14.244.15.16": {
                "DISK": 2,
                "L2TP": 2,
                "LOAD": 2,
                "OPENVPN TCP": 2,
                "OPENVPN UDP": 2,
                "PING": 4,
                "PPTP": 2,
                "PROCESS": 2,
                "USERS": 2,
                "XL2TPD": 2
            }
        }
    }
}';

$jsonData = json_decode($s);

echo '<table border=1>';
$titles = array_keys((array)current($jsonData->data->servicelist));

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>IP Address</td>';

foreach($titles as $col){

    echo '<td>' . $col . '</td>';
}
echo '<tr>';

foreach($jsonData->data->servicelist as $key => $data){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>$key</td>";
    foreach ($data as $prop => $val){
        echo "<td>$val</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';    
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Result =

[image]

Comment: this answer works but not as a solution to the question.
Anyways thanks a lot for the help!